# Order of python generator expression

Tags: python, generator, generator-expression

I have an example where the iteration order of a python generator expression seems to be different from the analogous list comprehension and generator function.

For example, the code

```
n = 10
d = {i : str(i) for i in range(n)}

for i in d:
    print d[i],
print

def func_gen(d):
    for i in range(n):
        yield d[i]

print(list(func_gen(d)))

g = [d[i] for i in range(n)]
print(g)

g = {d[i] for i in range(n)}
print(list(g))
```

has the output

```
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
['1', '0', '3', '2', '5', '4', '7', '6', '9', '8']
```

I would expect the generator expression to produce an ordered output like it does with the list comprehension. Is there something about generator expressions that
says the order isn't guaranteed?

Why is the order for the generator expression different from the others, even though the constructs are almost identical? It isn't even the same order as iterating through the dictionary, so it doesn't seem like
it's deferring to that.

I'm seeing the same behavior in Python 2 and 3.

Comment: Keep in mind that a dict does not have any particular order. In other words, original ordering of a dict is not preserved.

Comment: The ordering in those examples (I would think) is *not* determined by the dict, but by the iterators, which I would expect to be ordered in all cases.

Comment: @AJFriend: The ordering in the (last three) examples is determined by how they're converted to lists.  For a set, that conversion is unordered.

Comment: You are right. However, when you create a dict from the iterator, the ordering is *"lost"* because it is not stored/implemented anywhere.

Comment: @jwodder Thanks. I was just being dumb. In the last example, what I really wanted was `g = (d[i] for i in range(n))` to create a generator expression instead of a set. Stackoverflow's the best for finding silly mistakes. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dicts aren't ordered. You can't rely on their items to come back in any particular order, even between function calls.

Comment: Technically, what he's printing is a *set*, not a dict.  Still unordered, though.

Comment: The generator function certainly should returned ordered output, as should the list comprehension. I don't see how the generator expression would be any different from those two cases.

Comment: @jwodder Oh, you're right. I was thinking that the last one was a generator expression, but it is indeed a set. I want parenthesis. Thanks.

Comment: @jwodder A set is a dict without keys, more or less. But yeah, I meant set for the final line.